# How to use server‑side discovery in my NestJs project with Consul?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, consul

I am working with the nestjs project, and I can register my service to consul:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';

import * as Consul from 'consul';

import { ConsulRegistedService } from './consul-service-dto';

@Injectable()

export class ConsulService implements OnModuleInit {

privateconsul;

constructor() {

this.consul=newConsul({

host:'192.168.40.9',

port:8500,

secure:false,

promisify:true,

token:'d48f5',

});

}

asynconModuleInit():Promise<void> {

try {

constaddress='192.168.60.234';

constport=3567; // replace this with the actual port your service is listening on

constserviceId=`consulreg-service-${address}-${port}`;

awaitthis.consul.agent.service.register({

id:serviceId,

name:'consulreg-service',

address,

port:parseInt(String(port), 10),

// check: {

// http: `http://${address}:${port}/api/health`,

// interval: '30s',

// deregistercriticalserviceafter: '1m',

// },

});

process.on('SIGINT', async () => {

console.log(

'De-registering the service from Consul before shutting down...',

);

awaitthis.consul.agent.service.deregister(serviceId);

process.exit();

});

} catch (error) {

console.error('Failed to register with Consul', error);

process.exit(1);

}

}

// To Fetch

asyncgetServiceInstances(

serviceName:string,

): Promise<{ address: string; port: number }[]> {

try {

constservices=awaitthis.consul.agent.services();

constss=awaitthis.consul.catalog.service.list();

console.log(services);

constserviceInstances= (

Object.values(services) asConsulRegistedService[]

).filter((service) => service.Service === serviceName);

returnserviceInstances.map((service) => ({

address:service.Address,

port:service.Port,

}));

} catch (error) {

console.error(`Failed to get instances of service ${serviceName}`, error);

return [];

}

}

}
```

I can use this to register my service. Then I can use getServiceInstances to get the service

```
{
  'consulreg-service-192.168.60.234-3567': {
    ID: 'consulreg-service-192.168.60.234-3567',
    Service: 'consulreg-service',
    Tags: [],
    Meta: {},
    Port: 3567,
    Address: '192.168.60.234',
    TaggedAddresses: { lan_ipv4: [Object], wan_ipv4: [Object] },
    Weights: { Passing: 1, Warning: 1 },
    EnableTagOverride: false,
    Datacenter: 'dc1'
  }
}
```

In other services, they can use the address and port to access. This should be the client‑side discovery. However, I want to use the server‑side discovery; how can I use it in my nestjs project?